# Why does this tikz code produce two separate lines?

Tags: pdflatex, tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] grid (4,3);
\coordinate (X) at (3,3);
\draw[red ,thick,xshift=-10] (1,1 -|   X) -- (2,2 -|   X);
\draw[blue,thick,xshift=-10] (1,1 -| 3,3) -- (2,2 -| 3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

It seems that `xshift=-10` does not have any effect when the coordinate is specified by name. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer lies in that `X` is defined outside the scope of the `xshift=-10` transformation - see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38501/scope-yscale-not-transforming-coordinates/38507#38507) for details as well as possibly [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98924/transform-defined-coordinates-in-tikz) -, i.e. the node `X` is defined and has a fixed position before the beginning of the scope of the transformation which then is only applied to nodes newly defined within the scope.

an example may clarify things: extending the scope to include the definition of `X` shows the expected behavior with only one line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] grid (4,3);
      \begin{scope}[xshift=-10]
        \coordinate (X) at (3,3);
        \draw[red ,thick] (1,1 -|   X) -- (2,2 -|   X);
        \draw[blue,thick] (1,1 -| 3,3) -- (2,2 -| 3,3);
      \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: expected output - single line]